# Linkage error when calling super from property override

Tags: swift

I'm creating an `NSOperation` sub-class and using the following code fragment to manage the state and `ready` (as well as `executing` and `finished`) properties:

```
public class OperationGroup : NSOperation {

    enum ExecutionState {
        case Ready
        case Executing
        case Finished
    }

    var state:ExecutionState

    override public var ready:Bool {
        return state == .Ready && super.ready
    }

    override init() {
        state = .Ready
    }
}
```

When linking either through the REPL or as part of an application, I get the error:

```
Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage!
i8* ()* @_TFFC13__lldb_expr_114OperationGroupg5readySbaL_4selfS0_
invalid linkage type for function declaration
i8* ()* @_TFFC13__lldb_expr_114OperationGroupg5readySbaL_4selfS0_
```

The only way I've found around it so far is to omit the call to `super.ready`, which will work for my current project, but may break in the future if I try to use an `OperationGroup` in conjunction with dependencies.

Is this a compiler bug here in that either the compiler shouldn't let me invoke `super.ready` or it should actually work, or am I doing something incorrectly?

FWIW, if I change `state == .Ready && super.ready` to just `super.ready` it also compiles and links, but that's probably just the compiler optimizing the whole thing out.

Comment: FYI, I filed a bug report #18422804

Comment: So did I, abut a month ago, the more the merrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curiously, it works if you change the order from:

```
return state == .Ready && super.ready
```

to:

```
return super.ready && state == .Ready
```

Or, if the order really bothers you, you could:

```
if state != .Ready {
    return false
}
return super.ready
```

Regardless, it looks like a compiler bug to me, worthy of a bug report.

Comment: But, if you reverse the order, it short-circuits the wrong thing :)

Comment: @David I don't follow: The only difference is the order that they're checked, but functionally the result should be the same (it will only be `ready` when both are `true`). Regardless, it's a very curious little bug.

Comment: Operator short circuiting of && will prevent the 2nd expression from being evaluated if the first expression is false, so, optimally, you want the simplest expression first :)

Comment: @David Yes, agreed. I thought you were implying some functional problem, not just a performance problem. If the order in which they're evaluated bothers you, just make it explicit (as in more awkward alternative provided in the revised answer). IMHO, either of these work-arounds are better than having a `ready` property that breaks/omits the `super.ready` functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I had long since just flipped the two and hoped Apple would respond to the bug report